# What should be the appropriate nunit test case for the following code snippet?

Tags: testing, nunit, case

The following function is used to check if the play operation is possible or not. It returns **true** if play is possible else **false**. What should be the appropriate nunit test case for this method?

```
     private bool CanPlay(object parameter)
    {
        if (AudioEngine != null)
        {
            return AudioEngine.CanPlay;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private void Play(object parameter)
    {
        if (AudioEngine != null && AudioEngine.ActiveStream!=null)
        {
            AudioEngine.Play();
        }
    }
    [Test]
    public void PlayAudioControlVMTestTrue()
    {
        AudioControlVm avm = new AudioControlVm();
        RelayCommand command = (RelayCommand)avm.PlayCommand;
        bool canPlay = command.CanExecute(avm);
        Assert.IsTrue(canPlay); 
    }
```

Comment: Provide more details in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as follows:

```
    [Test]
    public void PlayAudioControlVMTestTrue()
    {
        AudioControlVm avm = new AudioControlVm();
        NAudioEngine.Instance.OpenFile(WAV_FILE_LOCATION);
        avm.AudioEngine.Play();
        RelayCommand command = (RelayCommand)avm.PlayCommand;
        bool canPlay = command.CanExecute(avm);
        Assert.IsTrue(canPlay);

        NAudioEngine.Instance.Stop();
    }
```